# Error saying that my methods are undefined

Tags: java

Ok, so I am following the Java tutorials on the [BrandonioProdtuctions](http://bit.ly/17algmZ) YouTube channel and. I am on Part 7:Intro to Object Oriented Programming. The problem I am having is that when I try to run the program it gives me errors in the class (titled objectIntroTest) that I have pasted directly below.

```
public class objectIntroTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String x = "Hello";
        objectIntro waterBottle = new objectIntro(0); 
        waterBottle.addwater(100); 
        waterBottle.drinkWater(20); 
        System.out.println("Your remaining water level is:"* + waterBottle.getWater());
    }
}
```

This is the other class, titled "objectIntro":

```
public class objectIntro {

    public objectIntro(){
        //Default constructor
    }
    public objectIntro(int waterAmount){
        twater = waterAmount;
    }

    int twater = 0; //This is how much water is in the water bottle
    public void addWater(int amount){
        twater = twater + amount;
    }
    public void drinWater(int amount){
        twater = twater - amount;
    }
    public int getWater(){
        return twater;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message it gives me when I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method addwater(int) is undefined for the type objectIntro
    The method drinkWater(int) is undefined for the type objectIntro
    The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

    at objectIntroTest.main(objectIntroTest.java:6)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `System.out.println("Your remaining water level is:"* + waterBottle.getWater());` is incorrect.  The `*` shouldn't be there, I think you have a type.  You may also want to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: The code that you posted here won't compile - you have a "}" right after the comment: `//Default constructor` and the `*` in SOP ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have 3 mistakes:
first: remove '*' from here : `System.out.println("Your remaining water level is:"* + waterBottle.getWater());`

second: your  method in `objectIntro` is `addWater` which you have used as `waterBottle.addwater(100);` ('W' must be captalized)

and the third: your other method in  `objectIntro` is `drinWater` but you have used incorrectly again:`waterBottle.drinkWater(20);`  (extra 'k')

be more careful and also check run time errors before compiling.

here is a website about naming conventions:
http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: +1 for listing everything...but you could add a comment about naming conventions

Comment: yes but when I posted this answer I didn't have enough reputation to post a comment on question. thanks for your remembrance.

Comment: Update your answer with a comment about naming conventions ;)

Answer (score 3):

spelling mistake

use `addWater` instead of `addwater`

I think you should check the java naming convention [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

specially [naming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) a variable says

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with
>   capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or
>   dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.
>
> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a
>   variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the
>   casual observer the intent of its use. One-character variable names
>   should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables. Common
>   names for temporary variables are i, j, k, m, and n for integers; c,
>   d, and e for characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
waterBottle.addWater(100);
```

instead of

```
waterBottle.addwater(100);
```

Meaningful method name Convention [here](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html)

Answer (score 1):

Latter case mistake `waterBottle.addwater(100);`  method is

```
addWater(int amount)
```

use

```
waterBottle.addWater(100);
```

Also remove * from

```
System.out.println("Your remaining water level is:"* + waterBottle.getWater());
```